# Where to put Apache vhost configuration (httpd-vhosts.conf or httpd.conf)?

Tags: apache

I just to ask a simple question. I am studying the vhost configuration but I am confused where should I properly put my vhosts configuration?

I have a file that has a name `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `httpd.conf`
I try to put my configuration in these 2 files but different web projects. And after I restarted my Wampserver I can access them. Is it fine if I place all my vhost entries in the file `httpd-vhosts.conf` ? Or should I place it in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong. Apache has one global config file, which typically is the default or specified in the startup script.

This file then uses one or more secondary config files and directories. Different Linux distributions use different default include directories.

On CentOS I think for example you would put a file (named like your domain but can be anything) in /etc/httpd/conf.d/example-com.conf: http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ApacheVhostDir